# Conversion from varchar2 to timestamp

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, timestamp, date-format

In a oracle table column, there is a `varchar2` column which contains value `'2017-02-14T18:04:34.988+00:00'` I need to convert it to timestamp. I am using `TO_TIMESTAMP()` to convert but I am not able to find out what date mask I need to provide. I have tried with

```
sql> select to_timestamp('2017-02-14T18:04:34.988+00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') from dual ;
```

But it does not work.

Kindly suggest what datetime mask I have to specify as 2nd argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) `T` is the time designator.
You need to use a constant `"T"` in your date format mask.

And your time stamp contains timezone so you need to use `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ` function to achieve this.

```
SQL> select to_timestamp_tz('2017-02-14T18:04:34.988+00:00',' YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM') from dual;

TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2017-02-14T18:04:34.988+00:00','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
14-FEB-17 06.04.34.988000000 PM +00:00
```

**Documentation:**[TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions230.htm#SQLRF06143)